# Google Calendar API - Invite Attendee via email

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a NodeJS API to add an event to google calendar. The event is getting added on the calendar but the attendees are not getting an invite email. However,the organiser gets the email 1 day before the event starts(Reminder time set).
This is my code

```
exports.setCalendar = function(request,response){
var addEventBody = {
    'status':'confirmed',
    'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
    'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google developer products.',
    'sendNotifications': true,
    'organizer': {
      'email': 'sujith@toobler.com',
      'self': true
    },
    'start': {
      'dateTime': request.body.startdate,
    },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': request.body.enddate
    },
    'attendees': [
        {
          'email': 'sujith@toobler.com',
          'organizer': true,
          'self': true,
          'responseStatus': 'needsAction'
        },
        {
        'email': request.body.contact.email,
        'organizer': false,
        'responseStatus': 'needsAction'
        }
    ],
    'reminders': {
        'overrides':[
            {
            'method' : 'email',
            'minutes' :'1440'
            },
            {
            'method' : 'popup',
            'minutes' :'1440'
            }
        ],
        'useDefault': false 
    },
    'gadget': {
        'display' : 'icon',
        'title' : 'titleee',
        'iconLink' : 'https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/medical-samples-in-test-tubes-couple_318-61810.jpg'
    }
  };

  var addGoogleEvent = function(accessToken){
    //instantiate google calendar instance
    var google_calendar = new gcal.GoogleCalendar(accessToken);
    google_calendar.events.insert('sujith@toobler.com', addEventBody, function(addEventError, addEventResponse){
      console.log('GOOGLE RESPONSE:', addEventError, addEventResponse);

      if(!addEventError)
        return response.send(200, addEventResponse);

        return response.send(400, addEventError);
    });
  };

    addGoogleEvent(req.body.accToken);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer. sendNotification key was to be send as a seperate param and not in the data.

```
exports.setCalendar = function(request,response){
var option = {
    'sendNotifications' : true
};
var addEventBody = {
'status':'confirmed',
'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google developer products.',
'organizer': {
  'email': 'sujith@toobler.com',
  'self': true
},
'start': {
  'dateTime': request.body.startdate,
},
'end': {
  'dateTime': request.body.enddate
},
'attendees': [
    {
      'email': 'sujith@toobler.com',
      'organizer': true,
      'self': true,
      'responseStatus': 'needsAction'
    },
    {
    'email': request.body.contact.email,
    'organizer': false,
    'responseStatus': 'needsAction'
    }
],
'reminders': {
    'overrides':[
        {
        'method' : 'email',
        'minutes' :'1440'
        },
        {
        'method' : 'popup',
        'minutes' :'1440'
        }
    ],
    'useDefault': false 
},
'gadget': {
    'display' : 'icon',
    'title' : 'titleee',
    'iconLink' : 'https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/medical-samples-in-test-tubes-couple_318-61810.jpg'
}
};

var addGoogleEvent = function(accessToken){
//instantiate google calendar instance
var google_calendar = new gcal.GoogleCalendar(accessToken);

google_calendar.events.insert('sujith@toobler.com', addEventBody,option, function(addEventError, addEventResponse){
  console.log('GOOGLE RESPONSE:', addEventError, addEventResponse);

  if(!addEventError)
    return response.send(200, addEventResponse);

    return response.send(400, addEventError);
});
};

 addGoogleEvent(req.body.accToken);
}
```

Comment: Also note, `sendNotification` has been deprecated now and replaced with `sendUpdates`:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert